# Failure with Routes in Virtual Host

Tags: php, apache, routes, router, virtualhost

I have a web project configured with a Router.php when I run my project with php -S localhost:8000 it works perfectly but when I put it in my virtual host the first route "/" is displayed correctly but it gives an error when it starts to run redirects.
I put part of my Router.php code, index.php and an example of how I redirect when an action is executed.

Router.php

```
<?php
namespace MVC;
class Router
{
    public array $getRoutes = [];
    public array $postRoutes = [];

    public function get($url, $fn)
    {
        $this->getRoutes[$url] = $fn;
    }

    public function post($url, $fn)
    {
        $this->postRoutes[$url] = $fn;
    }

    public function comprobarRutas()
    {
        $currentUrl = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

        if ($method === 'GET') {
            $fn = $this->getRoutes[$currentUrl] ?? null;
        } else {
            $fn = $this->postRoutes[$currentUrl] ?? null;
        }


        if ( $fn ) {

            call_user_func($fn, $this);
        } else {
            echo "Not found";
        }

    }

    public function render($view, $datos = [])
    {


        foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
            $$key = $value;
        }

        ob_start();

        include_once __DIR__ . "/views/$view.phtml";
        $contenido = ob_get_clean(); // Limpia el Buffer
        include_once __DIR__ . '/views/layout.phtml';
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../includes/app.php';

use MVC\Router;

use Controllers\LoginController;
use Controllers\DashboardController;

$router = new Router();


$router->get('/', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
$router->post('/', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
$router->get('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout']);

d
$router->get('/olvide', [LoginController::class, 'olvide']);
$router->post('/olvide', [LoginController::class, 'olvide']);


$router->get('/restablecer', [LoginController::class, 'restablecer']);
$router->post('/restablecer', [LoginController::class, 'restablecer']);

$router->get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index']);

$router->comprobarRutas();
```

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace Controllers;

use Classes\Email;
use Model\Usuario;
use MVC\Router;

class LoginController
{
    public static function login(Router $router)
    {

        $alertas = [];

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            $usuario = new Usuario;
            $usuario->email = $_POST['email'];
            $usuario->password = $_POST['password'];

            $alertas = $usuario->validarLogin();

            if (empty($alertas)) {

                $usuario = Usuario::where('email', $usuario->email);
                if (!$usuario || !$usuario->confirmado) {
                    Usuario::setAlerta('login', 'El Usuario No Existe o no esta confirmado');
                } else {
                    // El Usuario existe
                    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $usuario->password)) {

                        // Iniciar la sesión
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['id'] = $usuario->id;
                        $_SESSION['rol'] = $usuario->rol;
                        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $usuario->nombre;
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $usuario->email;
                        $_SESSION['id_trabajador'] = $usuario->id_trabajador;
                        $_SESSION['login'] = true;

                        // Redirection
                       ** header('Location: /dashboard');**
                    } else {
                        Usuario::setAlerta('login', 'Password Incorrecto');
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $alertas = Usuario::getAlertas();
        // Render a la vista 
        $router->render('auth/login', [
            'titulo' => 'Iniciar Sesión',
            'alertas' => $alertas
        ]);
}
```

My VirtualHost configuration

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Programacion/Desktop/osirias/public"
  ServerName osirias.localhost
  <Directory "C:/Users/Programacion/Desktop/osirias/public">
    Require all granted
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Normally you run it with php -S localhost:8000 and passing it to the apache virtual host fails to redirect to the routes

Comment: What was the error on Virtual Host?